# zipファイル内のファイル名を変更したい

Tags: ruby

```
# zipファイル名
zip_file_name= "test.zip"
# zipファイルパス
zip_file_path = File.join Rails.public_path, zip_file_name
# zipファイルに含ませるファイル
file = "xxxxxxx/xxxxx/test.txt"

`zip -jm #{zip_file_path } #{file}`  ①
FileUtils.chmod(0664, zip_file_path )②
'rm #{file}'③
```

①でtest.txtをtest.zipとして圧縮、
②でtest.zipファイルのパーミッション変更
③でtest.txtファイルを削除

zipファイルに含ませるファイルは変更せずに、
①でつくるzipファイルに含ませるファイル名をtest2.txtに変えることは可能でしょうか？

Comment: この手順であれば事前にリネームしてから圧縮すれば良さそうに見えますが、それでは駄目なのでしょうか（最終的に元ファイルは削除するようですし）。

Answer (score 1):

zip コマンドではなく、Ruby の Zip ライブラリを使用するのはどうでしょうか。

https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip

`Zip::File#add` の第一引数が Zip 内のファイル名、第二引数が格納したい実ファイル名です。

Answer (score 0):

質問は、「初期状態(与えられるデータ)："test.txt"ファイルを圧縮した"test.zip"ファイルがある。（"test.txt"ファイルは既に削除されていて存在しない）
希望する最終状態(結果として作られるデータ)："text.txt"と内容が同じでファイル名が"test2.txt"のファイルが、"test.txt"ファイルと置き換わった"test.zip"ファイル
」を満たす操作手順が知りたいという事だと思われます。

以下の操作で如何でしょう
 1. `$ unzip test.zip` コマンドでtest.zipを解凍して、"test.txt"ファイルを取り出す
 2. `$ zip -d test.zip test.txt`　コマンドでtest.zipから"test.txt"ファイルを削除する
 3. `$ mv test.txt test2.txt`コマンドでファイル名を"test.txt"から"test2.txt"に変更する
 4. `$ zip test.zip test2.txt` コマンドで"test2.txt"ファイルを"test.zip"ファイルに追加する